# how to use union types with parseInt?

Tags: typescript, parseint, union-types

I have a value coming in as a string, like "1.5"
If its a number I want it to be logged as a number.
This code will do the j

```
  // parse out the value as a number if it is one
  let val = parseFloat(event.value) || event.value;
  event.value = val;
```

where i have an Interface

```
interface IEvent {
  value: string | number;
  ...
}
```

But this gives an error as

> 'argument of type string|number is not assigned parameter string'

since parseInt expects a string.

How can i get around this, or just stop that warning?

Comment: But won't `value` **always** be a string?

Comment: good point, it always comes in as a string, but sometimes its a number. i guess I could use a different field in the interface for `in:string > out:number|string`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type guard to reduce the type:

```
let num = event.value;
if (typeof num === 'string'){
    num = parseFloat(num) || num;
}

event.value = num;
```

In this example, inside of the type guard, the type of `num` is simply `string`. Outside it remains `string | number`.